# HTML5 Form in Header

Tags: html, forms, header

Is the following part of the snippet valid? (I'm unsure about this)

```
<header id="outerHeader">

    <form>
        <!--LOGIN-->
    </form>

</header>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @user2864740 What's telling you that it's not valid? When you define doctype, head and body tag, it's completely valid html.

Comment: @DhirajShah *sigh* You're right. I had read/typed in `<head>` :>

Comment: Ok Thanks. Somebody told me that I cannot put a form tag inside the header.

Comment: @TyronimoDE You can definitely put search form, login form, navigation inside the header tag. If it's about semantics you care about, always read about the elements from html5doctor. For header tag, here's the link. http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/